# Sidebar controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sidebar

Is there any library available for making a Facebook type side menu  in swift.
I am trying to use SWRevealViewController to do it. But the problem is that SWRevealViewController is in objective c. I tried to use bridging header but I am unable to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might help,  https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu, A simple side menu for iOS 8 written in Swift language. Using UIDynamics, UIGestures and UIBlurEffect.

Comment: Hi This is a very good library to start with. Thanx for recommending it. I am trying to implement this on a tab bar controller. The problem which i am facing is that the tab bar doesnt move on the main view moves. Any suggestions for that.

Comment: heyy how to create slidebar menu in swift without using storyboard?? please help me